# (JavaScript) Trying to call a Method throught a CheckBox

Tags: javascript, php

Basically I have a PHP method that downloads a table from a database on a server (phone_table). That all works fine. When it prints the table the last column is just a checkbox, and its printed using this code throught the php:

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id=$i onlick=getSubtotal($i)" . $a[$j+1] . "</td>";
```

This is the method getSubtotal(a) from the JavaScript, complete with debugging alerts:

```
function getSubtotal(a) {
alert("called");
var table_ph = document.getElementById("phone_table");
var cellNo = table_ph.rows.item(a).cells;
var cellVal = document.getElementById(a);
alert("localStorage = " + localstorage.ttl);
alert("Called");

if(cellVal.checked == 1){
    cellVal = cellNo.item('5').textContent;
    var sub = parseFloat(localstorage.ttl);
    var num = parseFloat(cellVal);
    alert("Checked");
    sub = sub + num;
    localstorage.ttl = sub;
    document.getElementById("subtotal").innerHTML= "Your Subtotal is: &#163;" + localstorage.ttl;
    alert(localstorage.ttl);
} if(cellVal.checked == 0){
    cellVal = cellNo.item('5').textContent;
    var sub = parseFloat(localstorage.ttl);
    var num = parseFloat(cellVal);
    sub = sub - num;
    localstorage.ttl = sub;
    document.getElementById('subtotal').innerHTML= "Your Subtotal is: &#163;" + localstorage.ttl;
            }
}
```

Any Help would be brilliant, because this is driving me to distraction.
Cheers Guys,

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: It doesn't work. The method doesn't get called, and when it does the if statements are never accessed. Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: You have loads of errors in your HTML, no wonder it doesn't work.

Comment: What @putvande said. Plus you should read up on what "Separation of Concerns" is.

Comment: The Method is getting called now, but it will never actually go through any of the if-statements. Can You Help Me Understand Why Please?

Comment: @Kamon241 Check out my answer. You should really add an explanation on what you *want* your code to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you can change

```
if(cellVal.checked == 1) {
    // ...
}
if(cellVal.checked == 0) {
    // ...
}
```

to

```
if(cellVal.checked) {
     // ...
} else {
     // ...
}
```

Both blocks also share a lot of the lines (they're duplicated), so you can just put them before/after the `if` statement. Furthermore, this line is incorrect:

```
cellVal = cellNo.item('1').textContent;
```

`cellVal` is a reference to the DOM element. So changing it's value is done by

```
cellVal.value = cellNo.item('1').textContent;
```

The next thing is that your `id` attributes are not valid (they can't just be a number).

However – there is too much logic that seems out of place or plain wrong that I can't really improve without knowing what this code is supposed to do.

- What is `localstorage` there for? The name suggests similarity to the HTML5 `localStorage` , but it just doesn't do anything here.
- Why are you handling the `a` in so many ways? Why is it both an index and an id? This will especially not work anymore once you use valid ids.
- Guessing that you want to add up the values that are checked, I fail to see what `sub - num` would ever be useful for.

Finally, as mentioned before, you should learn about [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Don't mix HTML with Javascript.

---

**Edit**: Taking a wild guess at what you want to achieve, this is what I'd think: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GvkN2/2/)

<sub>(Note: My fiddle will only work for IE9+ due to `Array.prototype.forEach` and `document.querySelectorAll` usage. Those can be shimmed, though, or you can of course also use alternatives – but since I was just trying to take a guess I didn't care about browser compatibility).</sub>

Comment: YES!! That is what I was trying to do

Comment: Last and only question. If I wanted the 'price' column from the phone_tables, what should I call to replace your data-cost?

Comment: Sorry,  I don't understand. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing angle bracket on your input box and also are missing some single quotes around your attribute values.  You have:

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id=$i onlick=getSubtotal($i)" . $a[$j+1] . "</td>";
```

Make it this and see if it fixes the problem:

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='$i' onclick='getSubtotal($i)' />" . $a[$j+1] . "</td>";
```

**Update:**  As for your javascript, make sure you pass `(a-1)` to the rows.item collection since javascript uses 0-based counting!  Also you have hardcoded `cellNo.item('5')` -- if you want the 5th cell, make sure you change that to `cellNo.item('4')`:

```
function getSubtotal(a) {

    var table_ph = document.getElementById("phone_table");
    var cellNo = table_ph.rows.item(a-1).cells;
    var cellVal = document.getElementById(a);

    if(cellVal.checked == 1){
        cellVal = cellNo.item('5').textContent;
        var sub = parseFloat(localstorage.ttl);
        var num = parseFloat(cellVal);
        sub = sub + num;
        localstorage.ttl = sub;
        document.getElementById("subtotal").innerHTML= "Your Subtotal is: &#163;" + localstorage.ttl;
    }

    if(cellVal.checked == 0){
        cellVal = cellNo.item('5').textContent;
        var sub = parseFloat(localstorage.ttl);
        var num = parseFloat(cellVal);
        sub = sub - num;
        localstorage.ttl = sub;
        document.getElementById('subtotal').innerHTML= "Your Subtotal is: &#163;" + localstorage.ttl;
    }
}
```

**Update #2:**  Here is a working JSFIDDLE that does not 100% match your code, but should show you it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/GvkN2/

Comment: The `$a[$j+1]` doesn't matter, its to do with the columns being printed within the PHP method. Your Fix did get it accessing, but the JavaScript still isn't being run properly, are there any obvious errors within the JS?

Comment: The Values are correct, the very first 'called' alert is appearing, but it doesn't progress any further than that

Comment: The $i var is the number of the row that the checkbox is being checked at e.g. the 2nd row would pass 2

Comment: @Kamon241 -- javascript uses 0-based counting!  Just FYI that if you are on the second row, you actually need to pass a value of 1 to the `table_ph.rows.item(a-1)` collection like this.  I think this is probably where you are failing.

Comment: Cheers for the fiddle, although the fact that it didn't work for me didn't fill me with confidence. I think its a problem with my localstorage that is stopping it progressing